# Windows 8.1 Virtual Machine pointing to CentOS 7

Tags: windows-8.1, virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos, multi-boot

**How do I set up a virtual machine within windows 8.1 pointing to a CentOS 7 installation which I would like to install on the same physical box?**

I have been encountering all sorts of problems trying to set up dual boot CentOS 7 with windows 8.1.  Partly because CentOS 7 does not ship with the correct drivers for the graphics card on the computer in question, and partly because the hardware manufacturer might have set up the UEFI in a way that inhibits dual booting.  My research indicates that setting up a virtual machine within windows might be away to get around this.

I have read about virtual machine and about virtual box from oracle.  Are either of these free?  And **what high-level instructions would you give for structuring this in Windows 8.1?**  I can then use your macro-level instructions to frame subsequent research to develop actual methods.

Answer (score 0):

[**Virtual Machine**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) - An emulation of a particular computer system

[**VirtualBox**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) - A hypervisor for x86 computers from Oracle Corporation

A virtual machine is just that - a virtual computer inside yours. VirtualBox is a free program that enables you to create and run virtual machines.

Here's a video I found that will show how to install CentOS on VirtualBox: https://youtu.be/7pQIIQ-mY90

Comment: Where can I download a version of virtualbox that supports 64 bit OS?  I downloaded a version that only lets me install 32 bit OS.  Here the link I used: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Comment: @CodeMed The x86/amd64 version has both.